# JavaFX how to make login Button disapper after login

Tags: javafx, fxml

We try to implement a app with login and register feature.
But I do know how to remove those two button after a user login.
We use a toolbar to contain those two.

Comment: use controlfx http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the items from the toolbar. For example:

```
toolbar.getItems().remove(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the items like James said with

```
toolbar.getItems().remove(button);
```

or just hide the button with

```
button.setVisible(false);
```